# My Excel Save and Close Macro seems to be reopening my workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro assigned to a button that should save any changes and then close only `thisworkbook`. However, when it runs after saving and closing it immediately starts to download the workbook again.

Here is the code:

```
Sub SaveAndClose()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'setting workbook
    wb.Save 'saving workbook
    wb.Close (True) ' closing workbook
    Application.Quit 'shutting down Excel
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
Sub SaveAndClose()
    Application.Quit 'shutting down Excel
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'setting workbook
    wb.Save 'saving workbook
    wb.Close (True) ' closing workbook
End Sub
```

Comment: Shutting down Excel first will cause none of the other code to run.

Comment: I changed the code as Toni suggested and it now  saves and closes the workbook and Excel.

Comment: Please mark it as an answer. @TerryTewell